# Frameset not working in EDGE but works fine Mozilla/IE

Tags: html, iframe, frame, compatibility, frameset

I have a problem with an old website that is only used in the company INTRANET. The site works without problems with Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer, but with the Edge Browser it is not displayed correctly.

On EDGE the frameset is not displayed correctly.

Unfortunately I cannot upload the code in full as it contains sensitive data, I have created screenshots to make you understand the problem and I hope it is understandable.

HOMEPAGE --> and click for example on "Test1

[image: HOMEPAGE --> and click for example on "Test1"]

TEST1 --> it appears smoothly with all browsers

[image: TEST1 --> it appears smoothly with all browsers]

by clicking on the right frame, for example on "Test6"

[The content that should be displayed in the middle is displayed on the left side of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9WRp.png)

If, on the other hand, I open the page with Firefox or Internet Explorer, it is displayed correctly as requested by me

[With IE other Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU0Zv.png)

Here I try to put part of the code

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 5.0">
<meta NAME="keywords"
CONTENT="home">
</head>

<frameset framespacing="0" border="false" frameborder="0" cols="191,*">
  <frame name="Links" scrolling="no" noresize target="ROben" src="index_links.htm">
  <frameset rows="9%,*">
    <frame name="ROben" target="_RUnten" src="index_oben.htm" scrolling="no" noresize>
    <frame name="RUnten" src="index_text.htm" scrolling="auto" noresize target="_top">
  </frameset>
  <noframes>
  <body>
  <p>Diese Seite verwendet Frames. Frames werden von Ihrem Browser aber nicht unterstützt.</p>
  </body>
  </noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

```html
html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 5.0">
<base target="Links">
<title>Bereich Frame - TEST1</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!-- A {text-decoration : none;}-->
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" topmargin="5" leftmargin="5" marginwidth="5" marginheigth="5" text="#000000" link="#6699CC" vlink="#6699CC" alink="#FFCC33">
<font size="2" color="#000000" face="Arial, Geneva, Helvetica"><div align="left">

<table border="0" width="190">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" width="186"><font size="2" color="#000000"><u><b><br>
    </b>verfügbare Optionen:</u></font><p>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="21" valign="top" align="right"><font size="2" color="#000000"><a
    href="test6/test6.htm"><img src="../pics/arrow_r1.gif" border="0" width="15" height="14"></a></font></td>
    <td width="161"><a href="test6/test6.htm"><b><font size="2" color="000000">test6</font></b></a><font size="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="21" valign="top" align="right"></td>
    <td width="161"><br>
    <font size="2" color="#FFFFFF">...</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="21" valign="top" align="right"><font size="2" color="#000000"><a
    href="test7"><img src="../pics/arrow_r1.gif" border="0" width="15" height="14"></a></font></td>
    <td width="161"><a href="test7"><b><font size="2" color="#000000">test7</font></b></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="21" valign="top" align="right"></td>
    <td width="161"><br>
    <font size="2" color="#FFFFFF">...</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="21" valign="top" align="right"><font size="2" color="#000000"><a
    href="test8"><img src="../pics/arrow_r1.gif" border="0" width="15" height="14"></a></font></td>
    <td width="161"><a href="test8"><b><font size="2" color="#000000">test8</font></b></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="21" valign="top" align="right"></td>
    <td width="161"><br>
    <font size="2" color="#FFFFFF">...</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="21" valign="top" align="right"><font size="2" color="#000000"><a
    href="test9" target="_blank"><img src="../pics/arrow_r1.gif" border="0" width="15" height="14"></a></font></td>
    <td width="161"><a href="test9" target="_blank"><b><font size="2" color="#000000">test9</font></b></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="21"></td>
    <td width="161"><br>
    <font size="2" color="#FFFFFF">...</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="21"></td>
    <td width="161"><br>
    <br>
    <font size="2" color="#FFFFFF">...</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="21"></td>
    <td width="161"><font size="1" color="#000000"><a href="../info/downloadbeschr.htm"><b>Downloadinformationen</b></a></font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="21"></td>
    <td width="161"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div></font>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 5.0">
<title>TEST6</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!-- A {text-decoration : none;}-->
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" topmargin="5" leftmargin="5" marginwidth="5" marginheigth="5" text="#000000" link="#6699CC" vlink="#6699CC" alink="#FFCC33">
<font face="Arial, Geneva, Helvetica" size="2" color="#000000">

<table border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="640" background="../../pics/blau1.gif"><p align="left"><font
    size="3"><b>TEST6</b></font></td>
  </tr>
</table>

etc...etc...etc...
```

I hope I was clear, sorry for my English and thank you in advance.